# Grammar - How to match optional and required whitespaces before and after words?

Tags: regex, nearley, moo-lexer

I am using [nearley and moo](https://nearley.js.org/) to come up with a rather complex grammar.  It seems to be working fine EXCEPT for my whitespace requirements.  I need to **require** whitespace when needed and allow it when not while keeping the grammar unambiguous.

For example:

```
After dinner, I went to bed.
```

I need to require whitespace between the words but allow it around the comma.  So the following are also valid:

```
After dinner , I went to bed.
After dinner,I went to bed.
```

### Below is a quick nearley grammar trying to do this.
If you don't get the syntax, it's pretty easy to figure it out.

```
// Required whitespace
rws : [ \t]+
// Optional whitespace
ows : [ \t]*

sentence -> words %ows "," sentence
          | words

words    -> word %rws words
         -> word

word     -> [a-zA-Z]
```

The grammar may have issues but the idea is the same. This becomes an ambiguous grammar.  How can I define an unambiguous grammar, expecting optional and required whitespaces?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Nearly nor Moo but the regex could be `whitespace : (?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*|[ \t])` and your grammar would become `word %whitespace word`. Hopefully that makes sense and I didn't completely botch up the language.

Comment: Oooo.  Didn't think about that.  What is the initial `?:`

Comment: It's a non-capturing group. Not sure if it's relevant here though. Might get away with `([ \t]*,[ \t]*|[ \t])` or even just `[ \t]*,[ \t]*|[ \t]`. If you allow multiple spaces between words then `[ \t]*,[ \t]*|[ \t]+` would work

Comment: Which one worked for you? I can turn it into an answer and you can accept it if you'd like

Comment: I stripped off the `?:` on the first suggestion.  Go ahead and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Nearly nor Moo but the regex could be

```
whitespace : ([ \t]*,[ \t]*|[ \t])
```

and your grammar would become

```
word %whitespace word
```

Hopefully that makes sense and I didn't completely botch up the language.

Answer (score 2):

I find that using [moo-lexer](/questions/tagged/moo-lexer) makes my grammar simpler and I generally spend less time fixing ambiguous grammars as a result.

I'm not an expert in designing grammar but this is what I'd do:

**lexer.js**

- `word` will match a sequence of characters
- `comma` will match `" , "`, `" ,"`, `", "` and `","`.
- `space` will match a single space `" "`
- `period` will match a single period `"."`
- `nl` will match one or more newlines.

```js
const moo = require('moo');

const lexer =
  moo.compile
    ( { word: /[a-zA-Z]+/
      , comma:/ ?, ?/
      , space: / /
      , period: /\./
      , nl: {match: /\n+/, lineBreaks: true}
      }
    );

module.exports = lexer;
```

**grammar.ne**

Here we say:

1. A text has one or more sentences
2. Newlines can occur before and after each sentence
3. A sentence *may* start with a sequence of `%word` followed by either a `%comma` or a `%space` *and* must finish with a `%word` followed by a `%period.`

All the post-processing rules are flattening list of tokens and extract `.value` from tokens so that we end up with lists of words.

```
@{% const lexer = require("./lexer.js"); %}
@lexer lexer

text
  -> %nl sentence:+ {% ([_, sentences]) => sentences %}

sentence
  -> seq:* %word %period %nl {% ([seq, w, p, n]) => [...seq, w.value] %}

seq
  -> (%word %space) {% ([[w]]) => w.value %}
   | (%word %comma) {% ([[w]]) => w.value %}
```

This grammar allows to parse this text:

```
After breakfast, I went to work.

After lunch , I went to my desk.

After the pub,I went home.

sleep.
```

Example:

```js
const nearley = require('nearley');
const grammar = require('./grammar.js');

const parser = new nearley.Parser(nearley.Grammar.fromCompiled(grammar));

parser.feed(`

After breakfast, I went to work.

After lunch , I went to my desk.

After the pub,I went home.

sleep.
`);

if (parser.results.length > 1) throw new Error('grammar is ambiguous');
JSON.stringify(parser.results[0], null, 2);
```

Output:

```json
[
  [
    "After",
    "breakfast",
    "I",
    "went",
    "to",
    "work"
  ],
  [
    "After",
    "lunch",
    "I",
    "went",
    "to",
    "my",
    "desk"
  ],
  [
    "After",
    "the",
    "pub",
    "I",
    "went",
    "home"
  ],
  [
    "sleep"
  ]
]
```